# EMIF interface between FPGA (virtex5) and TI - DDUC GC6016

Tags: fpga

I am trying to interface the FPGA and Texas DDUC GC6016 with EMIF interface.
I am a little bit confused in the part of interface: can you help me out?

Problem: the data(16bit), address (8bit), write enable, chip select, data read enable is coming to FPGA from PCI. I have to receive these data and send as per the enable signals and respected addresses to external DDUC chip which is having the same signals as a inputs to communicate.

Does any one know the logic to implement?

Comment: Does your FPGA already have PCI interface logic in it?

Comment: @sandeep: You really need to be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish. Is the FPGA acting as a bridge or is it processing the data or what? It sounds like you just want to pass on the data from the PCI to the DDUC but route it through the FPGA for some reason. It is unclear though. It sounds like a rather simple application in FPGA though.

Comment: thanks , i mean fpga has to configure the gc6016 and receive the data from pci and transfer to gc6016, the board has pci too.